# How to obtain opened editor window count in netbeans platform application?

Tags: netbeans-platform

In a simple netbeans platform application i want to obtain opened editor window count. How can I obtain that?

Answer (score 0):

This is answered in the NetBeans Platform developer FAQ:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqGetOpenEditorWindows

Good resource to learn about little tricks and idioms!